# Filtering counts in Pandas .agg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create a new Pandas Dataframe with specific counts from an existing dataframe (grouping by date and department).

I have read the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html

and have constructed the following:

```
new_values = df.groupby(['department',pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).agg({'id':"count", 'confirmed':"count"})
```

I am having difficulty with the syntax, as I want the second count to count only where 'confirmed'=='1'.

I can do this using a second dataframe

```
filtered_values = df[df['confirmed']==1]
```

taking another count, and then merging them back together, however, is there a way to do it in the aggregate listed above?

Comment: What values can confirmed take? Just 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, right now it would just be 0 or 1

Comment: Then you could use sum instead of count

Comment: `.agg({'id':"count", 'confirmed':lambda x: (x==1).sum()})` or like the previous comment `"sum"` instead of the lambda

Answer (score 0):

If the values are just `(0, 1)`, you can do directly:

```
new_values = df.groupby(['department',pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).agg({'id':"count", 'confirmed': lambda x: x.sum()})
```

In any other case (more different values) you can do:

```
new_values = df.groupby(['department',pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).agg({'id':"count", 'confirmed': lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()})
```

Comment: Great!  In this case they are, however, they will not always be - if I take the second variation, I am guessing I could swap it out to "true" and "False" rather than 1 and 0 if those were the values?  I'll test it.

Comment: I just tried .agg({'id':"count", 'confirmed':lambda x: (x==1).count()}), it does not appear the filter (x==1) works with the count() and I will have to stick with sum().  If the values were different (such as strings stating "True" and "False"_ would I still simply stick with sum()?

Comment: Yes True == 1, and False == 0, so you can stick with sum.